# Download pubmed papers based on DOI from sci-hub API in python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, pubmed, doi

In python 3.5, for downloading some papers from **pubmed** based on their **DOI** I've been used this link on **github** https://github.com/antiufo/scihub.py

first of all I installed all packages and the I copied this class https://github.com/antiufo/scihub.py/blob/master/scihub/scihub.py into my project after that in a new project besides **scihub.py** I've been created an object from  **SciHub class** for downloading and fetching paper by it's **DOI** such as below :

In this link : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28440475 **DOI** is : **10.3892/or.2017.5600** that I want to download this paper.

```
from scihub import SciHub

sh = SciHub()

result = sh.fetch(identifier='10.3892/or.2017.5600')
print(result)
result = sh.download(identifier='10.3892/or.2017.5600', destination='D:\me',path='myPdfFile.pdf')
```

but nothing happened.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried directly on terminal, using the command

```
python2 scihub.py -d https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.76.036111
```

In this case I have to put **https://doi.org/** and after the DOI, it's working perfectly in this case. If you use the SciHub API like a package you could try use the identifier with **https://doi.org/** .

I hope to help you.